# How to create separate layout for each user type

Tags: layout, aurelia

I've build an api using Hapijs that has two type of users ( admins and subscribers ) each type has its own ( model, controller, and restful routes for [create, delete, show, update, login ....] )
My question is how to create two separate layout (each layout has its own login page and others pages) for each user type in Aurelia ? 
Please help.

Comment: Would the different layouts share a single viewmodel class?

Comment: check out my writeup here for some ideas: http://davismj.me/portfolio/sentry/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. I think you are asking how to render certain items for only admin or vice versa. There are a few ways that you can do it, but here's how I've done it. You will have some sort of login page. Once the user logs in, you will create an object for that user.   This object will hold stuff such as user ID, first name, last name, or whatever you want. I wouldn't store anything sensitive in it. The most important thing to store is the role of the user. Meaning, you should have a property that states whether the user is an administrator or not.

Once the user has logged in, you just have to inject that object into your other view models so you can access it. From there you can render elements based on role by using the if.bind. So you'd do something like . In this case, your binding a true or false variable to the element. If the variable "isAdmin" is true, the element will be rendered onto the DOMAIN, otherwise, it will be removed from the DOM.

Sorry if the formatting is a little off, I'm on my phone.

Comment: First thank you for your help.
the two type (admins and subscriber each one  has its own entry-point for login, for example localhost/api/admins/login and localhost/api/subscribers/login) how to deal with this kind of scenario ?

Comment: @smahi Just create two different view/view-models. I'm not sure I understand what the issue is.